# Construct a master curve from data

Tags: data

I will try to be as informative as possible.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

I have the following data

```
data91 = {{-0.209091`, 2.89296`}, {0.281818`, 2.92958`}, {0.8`, 
    2.97535`}, {1.28182`, 3.03028`}, {1.8`, 3.07606`}, {2.28182`, 
    3.11268`}, {2.5`, 3.1493`}, {2.8`, 3.18592`}};

data88 = {{-0.2`, 2.74648`}, {0.272727`, 2.79225`}, {0.8`, 
    2.83803`}, {1.27273`, 2.8838`}, {1.80909`, 2.92958`}, {2.28182`, 
    2.95704`}, {2.50909`, 2.99366`}, {2.8`, 3.03028`}};

data85 = {{-0.209091`, 2.58169`}, {0.272727`, 2.63662`}, {0.790909`, 
    2.69155`}, {1.27273`, 2.74648`}, {1.8`, 2.77394`}, {2.28182`, 
    2.81972`}, {2.50909`, 2.82887`}, {2.8`, 2.87465`}};

data82 = {{-0.2`, 2.43521`}, {0.281818`, 2.49014`}, {0.8`, 
    2.55423`}, {1.27273`, 2.59085`}, {1.8`, 2.63662`}, {2.28182`, 
    2.66408`}, {2.50909`, 2.69155`}, {2.8`, 2.71901`}};

data79 = {{-0.2`, 2.27958`}, {0.281818`, 2.33451`}, {0.790909`, 
    2.38944`}, {1.27273`, 2.43521`}, {1.80909`, 2.48099`}, {2.28182`, 
    2.50845`}, {2.5`, 2.52676`}, {2.81818`, 2.56338`}};

data76 = {{-0.2`, 2.07817`}, {0.272727`, 2.14225`}, {0.790909`, 
    2.21549`}, {1.28182`, 2.27042`}, {1.80909`, 2.30704`}, {2.27273`, 
    2.36197`}, {2.5`, 2.37113`}, {2.8`, 2.40775`}};

data73 = {{-0.2`, 1.83099`}, {0.272727`, 1.93169`}, {0.790909`, 
    2.01408`}, {1.28182`, 2.07817`}, {1.80909`, 2.14225`}, {2.29091`, 
    2.16972`}, {2.50909`, 2.20634`}, {2.80909`, 2.2338`}};

data70 = {{-0.2`, 1.54718`}, {0.281818`, 1.65704`}, {0.8`, 
    1.77606`}, {1.29091`, 1.84014`}, {1.8`, 1.92254`}, {2.29091`, 
    1.97746`}, {2.50909`, 1.99577`}, {2.80909`, 2.03239`}};

data67 = {{-0.2`, 1.21761`}, {0.281818`, 1.32746`}, {0.8`, 
    1.47394`}, {1.27273`, 1.57465`}, {1.80909`, 1.6662`}, {2.28182`, 
    1.72113`}, {2.50909`, 1.7669`}, {2.80909`, 1.80352`}};

data64 = {{-0.2`, 0.869718`}, {0.263636`, 1.0162`}, {0.781818`, 
    1.15352`}, {1.29091`, 1.26338`}, {1.80909`, 1.39155`}, {2.29091`, 
    1.46479`}, {2.5`, 1.51972`}, {2.80909`, 1.55634`}};

data61 = {{-0.2`, 0.622535`}, {0.272727`, 0.714085`}, {0.809091`, 
    0.851408`}, {1.28182`, 0.988732`}, {1.79091`, 1.09859`}, {2.28182`, 
    1.21761`}, {2.5`, 1.25423`}, {2.81818`, 1.3`}};

data58 = {{-0.209091`, 0.411972`}, {0.272727`, 0.494366`}, {0.8`, 
    0.63169`}, {1.28182`, 0.723239`}, {1.80909`, 0.851408`}, {2.3`, 
    0.961268`}, {2.5`, 1.02535`}, {2.80909`, 1.07113`}};

data55 = {{-0.209091`, 0.265493`}, {0.281818`, 0.338732`}, {0.8`, 
    0.430282`}, {1.28182`, 0.521831`}, {1.8`, 0.640845`}, {2.28182`, 
    0.759859`}, {2.50909`, 0.796479`}, {2.80909`, 0.860563`}};

data52 = {{-0.209091`, 0.183099`}, {0.281818`, 0.219718`}, {0.790909`, 
    0.292958`}, {1.28182`, 0.375352`}, {1.80909`, 0.466901`}, {2.28182`, 
    0.576761`}, {2.49091`, 0.61338`}, {2.80909`, 0.677465`}};

data49 = {{-0.209091`, 0.109859`}, {0.272727`, 0.146479`}, {0.8`, 
    0.201408`}, {1.28182`, 0.256338`}, {1.80909`, 0.338732`}, {2.28182`, 
    0.430282`}, {2.50909`, 0.466901`}, {2.8`, 0.521831`}};
```

Here is their visualization:

```
    temps = -{91, 88, 85, 82, 79, 76, 73, 70, 67, 64, 61, 58, 55, 52, 49};
    ListLinePlot[{data91, data88, data85, data82, data79, data76, data73, 
data70, data67, data64, data61, data58, data55, data52, data49}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], Axes -> False, 
     PlotMarkers -> {{\[EmptyCircle], Medium}}, 
     PlotStyle -> Map[ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-91, -49}}], temps], 
     PlotLegends -> Quantity[temps, "DegreesCelsius"], ImageSize -> 600, 
     FrameLabel -> {"log\[Omega]", "E'(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(0\)]\)/T)"}, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[14], RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

`-61oC` is chosen as the reference temperature. What I want now is to shift horizontally the points of the other temperatures in order to construct a "master" curve at `-61oC` which spans a bigger range of `log\[Omega]` values. I can do this manually as follows

```
data49shift = data49 /. {x_, y_} -> {x - 3.5, y};
data52shift = data52 /. {x_, y_} -> {x - 2.8, y};
data55shift = data55 /. {x_, y_} -> {x - 2, y};
data58shift = data58 /. {x_, y_} -> {x - 1, y};
data64shift = data64 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 1.2, y};
data67shift = data67 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 2.5, y};
data70shift = data70 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 4.1, y};
data73shift = data73 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 5.8, y};
data76shift = data76 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 7.4, y};
data79shift = data79 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 8.9, y};
data82shift = data82 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 10.6, y};
data85shift = data85 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 12.2, y};
data88shift = data88 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 14., y};
data91shift = data91 /. {x_, y_} -> {x + 15.7, y};
```

and the result is

```
ListLinePlot[{data91shift, data88shift, data85shift, data82shift, 
  data79shift, data76shift, data73shift, data70shift, data67shift, 
  data64shift, data61, data58shift, data55shift, data52shift, 
  data49shift}, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], 
 Axes -> False, PlotMarkers -> {{\[EmptyCircle], Medium}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Map[ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-91, -49}}], temps], 
 PlotLegends -> Quantity[temps, "DegreesCelsius"], ImageSize -> 600, 
 FrameLabel -> {"log\[Omega]", 
   "E'(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(0\)]\)/T)"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[14], RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

The article that I follow says that the authors made the horizontal shifting in OriginPro but they do not provide any further information. Since I do not have OriginPro I am trying to develop a less manual procedure in Mathematica. 
Any ideas?

The algorithm should be such, that given two sets of data (the one of the reference temperature and the one to be shifted) it will make the horizontal shifting and return the horizontal shift factor for the best possible shifting.

E.g. for `data91` it will evaluate a value close to 15.7 that I found with the eye.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think this question is about Mathematica. The problem is that you don't know what algorithm to use in order to calculate the horizontal shift, not that you don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Should I delete the question?

Comment: @dimitris No,please.Going to post an answer in a few mins

Comment: So the idea is to shift the curves left and right, so they assemble into one smooth curve?

Comment: @belisariusisforth: Ok! Thanks in advance for your time! @ LLlAMnYP: Exactly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's first make interpolations of the data:

```
data = {data91, data88, data85, data82, data79, data76, data73, 
   data70, data67, data64, data61, data58, data55, data52, data49};

ints = Interpolation /@ data;
```

Now define a routine that shifts the curves in the set above the 61 deg curve so that their left-most point touches the next curve (recursively, so that previous shifts are taken care of). For the curves below the 61 deg curve shift such that the right-most point touches its neighbor.

```
ClearAll[sol]
master = 11; (* position of the reference curve in the data list *)
sol[i_ /; i < master] := 
 sol[i] = m /. 
   Last@NMinimize[
         {
          EuclideanDistance[
            {data[[i, 1, 1]] + m, ints[[i]][data[[i, 1, 1]]]}, 
            {k + sol[i + 1]     , ints[[i + 1]][k]          }
          ], 
          data[[i + 1, 1, 1]] <= k <= data[[i + 1, -1, 1]]
        }, {{m, 0.1, 0.8}, {k, 0.1, 0.2}}
       ]
sol[i_ /; i > master] := 
 sol[i] = m /. 
   Last@NMinimize[
          {
            EuclideanDistance[
              {data[[i, -1, 1]] + m, ints[[i]][data[[i, -1, 1]]]}, 
              {k + sol[i - 1]      , ints[[i - 1]][k]           }
            ], 
            data[[i - 1, 1, 1]] <= k <= data[[i - 1, -1, 1]]
          }, {{m, 0.1, 0.8}, {k, 0.1, 0.2}}
        ]
sol[master] = 0;
```

Calculate all shifts:

```
shifts = sol /@ Range[Length@data]
(* {14.0704, 12.49, 11.0173, 9.66209, 8.18936, 6.57826, \
5.09644, 3.68002, 2.3482, 1.0713, 0, -1.14927, -2.02456, -2.89625, \
-3.65812} *)
```

Apply shifts:

```
dataShift = MapIndexed[Function[v, {#1, 0} + v] /@ data[[#2[[1]]]] &, shifts];
```

And plot:

```
temps = -{91, 88, 85, 82, 79, 76, 73, 70, 67, 64, 61, 58, 55, 52, 49};

ListLinePlot[dataShift, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.1], Axes -> False, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{○, Medium}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Map[ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-91, -49}}], temps], 
 PlotLegends -> Quantity[temps, "DegreesCelsius"], ImageSize -> 600, 
 FrameLabel -> {"logω", 
   "E'(\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(0\)]\)/T)"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[14], RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Damn. Beat me by a min :) +1.

Comment: @belisariusisforth Good that I posted the code first and added comments later ;-P

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Will post a variation then :)

Comment: @belisariusisforth Not a simple and boring one with `FindRoot` or `NSolve` I hope?   ;-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries nah, I was minimizing the Abs of the integral of the difference of the interpolating functions. It works, but it is too slow

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks for the amazing solution. I will wait for other replies, otherwise I will choose it your solution.

Comment: @belisarius is forth: Time is not an issue for me. If you have time post your answer.

Comment: @Chris True, but I kept it this way to keep this part of the code similar to the next part (`ints[[i + 1]][k]`). For generating the plot the speed difference would be negligible.

Comment: Instead of trying to calculate the shifts based on `sol[master]=0` you may set `sol[1]=0` and afterwards add the `data11` offset to all of them. By doing that you don't need two `sol[ x_ /; cond] := ...` conditions but just one-for all.

Comment: @bel The forth is strong in you

Answer (score 13):

As Sjoerd treacherously spoiled my answer I'm posting an interpolation (slower) version that spans a 10% larger domain:

---

**Edit**

The following replacement in the code below serves the same function and is much faster, but it exploits a geometric symmetry of your particular curves:

```
bestShift[{d1_List, d2_List}] :=(x /. FindRoot[superpos[d1, d2, x], {x, -1, -2, 0}, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 3])
```

---

```
data = {data91, data88, data85, data82, data79, data76, data73, 
   data70, data67, data64, data61, data58, data55, data52, data49};

dataS = SortBy[data, #[[1, 2]] &]; 
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]; 
superpos[d1_, d2_, x_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{f1 = Interpolation@d1, f2 = Interpolation[{x, 0} + # & /@ d2], dom},
  dom = IntervalIntersection @@ ((Interval @@ 
                     InterpolatingFunctionDomain[#]) & /@ {f1, f2}) // First;
  Abs@NIntegrate[f1@y - f2@y, {y, dom[[1]], dom[[2]]}]
  ]

(* replace with the function in the edit above *)
bestShift[{d1_List, d2_List}] := (x /. 
                      Last@NMinimize[{superpos[d1, d2, x], -2 <= x <= 0}, x, 
                             AccuracyGoal -> 3, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"])

bs = bestShift /@ Partition[data, 2, 1]

(* we want data[[11]] not shifted *)

accBs = # - #[[11]] &@Join[{0}, Accumulate@bs]
(*
 {16.0986, 14.5014, 12.818, 11.1625, 9.38324, 7.5946, 5.87548, 
  4.19353, 2.58556, 1.19733, 0., -1.03404, -1.93369, -2.7309, -3.44727}
*)
MapThread[Function[{d, s}, {s, 0} + # & /@ d], {data, accBs}, 1] // ListLinePlot
```

### [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then you can build a smooth interpolating function:

```
pts = Sort[Join @@ MapThread[Function[{d, s}, {s, 0} + # & /@ d], {data, accBs}, 1]];
smooth = Transpose[GaussianFilter[#, 5] & /@ Transpose@pts];
f = Interpolation[smooth];
dom = First@InterpolatingFunctionDomain@f;
Plot[f@x, {x, dom[[1]], dom[[2]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: All this back and forth could take us sideways (e.g. Lie bracket !=0, so we can parallel park our cars).

Comment: Hey, what took you so long? You used to be faster, hehe. +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

i have data of thermomecanical .it is possible to introduire tts superposition principe to create master curve of creep by WLF equation and arrhensius

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/117400)

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code (and images, if helpful) to describe the challenge you face in a new post. While you are here, please don't forget to take the [Site Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and to visit the [Help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help) page. Thanks.